# Command line argument causing heap corruption

Tags: c, heap-corruption

I'm trying to write a buffer using C, it was supposed to take in contents from an input file and output it to another text file. However, when I try to debug it in Visual Studio 2019, it always trigger a breakpoint at `if ((fi = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL){...}` of my test file, it also detected a critical error of C0000374.  My command line argument is `buffer.exe ass1.pls a`

My test file : platy_bt.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#include "buffer.h"


/*check for ANSI C compliancy */
#define ANSI_C 0
#if defined(__STDC__)
#undef ANSI_C
#define ANSI_C 1
#endif

/*  Declaration of an error printing function with
 *  variable number of arguments
 */
void err_printf(char *fmt, ...);
/*  Declaration of a buffer contents display function */
void display (Buffer *ptr_Buffer); 
long get_filesize(char *fname);

int main(int argc, char **argv){

   pBuffer ptr_Buffer;   /* pointer to Buffer structure */
   FILE *fi;             /* input file handle */
   int loadsize = 0;     /* the size of the file loaded in the buffer */
   int ansi_c = !ANSI_C; /* ANSI C compliancy flag */
   char symbol;          /* symbol read from input file */ 
/* Check if the compiler option is set to compile ANSI C */
/* __DATE__, __TIME__, __LINE__, __FILE__, __STDC__ are predefined preprocessor macros*/
  if(ansi_c){
    err_printf("Date: %s  Time: %s",__DATE__, __TIME__);
    err_printf("ERROR: Compiler is not ANSI C compliant!\n");
    exit(1);
  }

/* missing file name or/and mode parameter */
  if (argc <= 2){

     err_printf("\nDate: %s  Time: %s",__DATE__, __TIME__);
     err_printf("\nRuntime error at line %d in file %s\n", __LINE__, __FILE__);
      err_printf("%s\b\b\b\b%s%s",argv[0],": ","Missing parameters.");
      err_printf("Usage: platybt source_file_name mode");
      exit(1);
    }

/* create a source code input buffer */     
    switch(*argv[2]){
     case 'f': case 'a': case 'm': break;
     default:
      err_printf("%s%s%s",argv[0],": ","Wrong mode parameter.");
      exit(1);
    }
/*create the input buffer */
    ptr_Buffer = b_allocate(0,0,*argv[2]);




    if (ptr_Buffer == NULL){
        err_printf("%s%s%s",argv[0],": ","Cannot allocate buffer.");
        exit(1);
    }

/* open the source file */
    if ((fi = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL){
        err_printf("%s%s%s%s",argv[0],": ", "Cannot open file: ",argv[1]);
        exit (1);
    }

/* load a source file into the input buffer  */
     printf("Reading file %s ....Please wait\n",argv[1]);
     loadsize = b_load (fi,ptr_Buffer);
     if(loadsize == RT_FAIL_1)
       err_printf("%s%s%s",argv[0],": ","Error in loading buffer.");

/*if the input file has not been completely loaded, find the file size and print the last symbol loaded */
    if (loadsize == LOAD_FAIL){
      printf("The input file %s %s\n", argv[1],"has not been completely loaded.");
      symbol = (char)fgetc(fi);
      printf("Last character read from the input file is: %c %d\n", symbol, symbol);
      printf("Input file size: %ld\n", get_filesize(argv[1]));
    } 

/* close source file */
   fclose(fi);

/* display the contents of the input buffer */    
   display(ptr_Buffer);

/* compact the buffer
 * add end-of-file character (EOF) to the buffer
 * display again
 */
if(!b_compact(ptr_Buffer,EOF)){         
      err_printf("%s%s%s",argv[0],": ","Error in compacting buffer.");
  }  
  display(ptr_Buffer); 

/* free the dynamic memory used by the buffer */  
  b_free(ptr_Buffer);
/* make the buffer invalid
   It is not necessary here because the function terminates anyway,
   but will prevent run-time errors and crashes in future expansions
*/
  ptr_Buffer = NULL;
/*return success */
  return (0);
}

/* error printing function with variable number of arguments*/
void err_printf( char *fmt, ... ){
/*Initialize variable list */   
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, fmt);

  (void)vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
   va_end(ap);

  /* Move to new line */
  if( strchr(fmt,'\n') == NULL )
     fprintf(stderr,"\n");
}

void display (Buffer *ptr_Buffer){
  printf("\nPrinting buffer parameters:\n\n");
  printf("The capacity of the buffer is:  %d\n",b_capacity(ptr_Buffer));
  printf("The current size of the buffer is:  %d\n", b_addcoffset(ptr_Buffer));
  printf("The operational mode of the buffer is:   %d\n",b_mode(ptr_Buffer));
  printf("The increment factor of the buffer is:  %lu\n",b_incfactor(ptr_Buffer));
  printf("The first symbol in the buffer is:  %c\n", b_addcoffset(ptr_Buffer)?*b_location(ptr_Buffer, 0):' ');
  printf("The value of the flags field is: %04hX\n",ptr_Buffer->flags);
  printf("\nPrinting buffer contents:\n\n");
  b_rewind(ptr_Buffer);
  if (!b_print(ptr_Buffer,1)) printf("empty buffer\n");
}

long get_filesize(char  *fname){
   FILE *input;
   long flength;
   input = fopen(fname, "r");
   if(input == NULL){
      err_printf("%s%s","Cannot open file: ",fname);  
      return 0;
   }
   fseek(input, 0L, SEEK_END);
   flength = ftell(input);   
   fclose(input);
   return flength;
}
<!-- -->
```

My buffer.c

```
#include "buffer.h";
#include <string.h>;
#include <stdlib.h>;
Buffer* b_allocate(short init_capacity, char inc_factor, char o_mode) {

    char* characterArray;

    if(init_capacity <0 ||  init_capacity >= SHRT_MAX) {
        printf("Capacity exceed the limit, must be between 0 and %d.", SHRT_MAX);

        return NULL;

    }



    else {

        pBuffer bufferStructure = (pBuffer) calloc(init_capacity, sizeof(Buffer));
        if (init_capacity == 0) {
            init_capacity = DEFAULT_INIT_CAPACITY;

            if (o_mode=='a' || o_mode== 'm') {

                inc_factor = DEFAULT_INC_FACTOR;
                bufferStructure->inc_factor = inc_factor;
            }
            else {
                if (o_mode== 'f') {
                    inc_factor = 0;
                    bufferStructure->inc_factor = inc_factor;
                }
            }

            characterArray = (char *) malloc(DEFAULT_INIT_CAPACITY);


        }
        else {

            characterArray = (char*) malloc(init_capacity);
        }



        bufferStructure->cb_head = characterArray;
        if (inc_factor == 0 && init_capacity != 0) {
            bufferStructure->mode = 0;
            bufferStructure->inc_factor = 0;


        }

        switch (o_mode) {
        case 'f':
            bufferStructure->mode = 0;
            bufferStructure->inc_factor = 0;
            break;
        case 'a':




            if (inc_factor >= 1 && inc_factor <= 255) {
                bufferStructure->mode = 1;
                bufferStructure->inc_factor = inc_factor;
                break;


            }
            else {
                if (inc_factor != 0) {
                    return NULL;
                    break;
                }
            }
        case 'm':
            if (inc_factor >= 1 && inc_factor <= 100) {
                bufferStructure->mode = -1;
                bufferStructure->inc_factor = inc_factor;
                break;


            }
            else {
                if (inc_factor != 0) {
                    return NULL;
                    break;
                }
            }

            }
        bufferStructure->capacity =  200;

        bufferStructure->flags = DEFAULT_FLAGS;
        bufferStructure->addc_offset = 0;
        bufferStructure->getc_offset = 0;
        bufferStructure->markc_offset;

        return bufferStructure;




        }




    }

    pBuffer b_addc(pBuffer const pBD, char symbol) {
        int inc_factor = pBD->inc_factor - '0';
        int newCapacity = 0;
        int availableSpace =0;
        long newIncrement = 0;


        pBD->flags &= RESET_R_FLAG;
        char* ptr;

        if (pBD->addc_offset <= pBD->capacity) {
            pBD->cb_head[pBD->addc_offset] = symbol;
            pBD->addc_offset++;

            return pBD;
        }
        else {
            switch (pBD->mode) {
            case 0:
                return NULL;
                break;
            case 1:

                newCapacity = pBD->capacity + inc_factor;

                if (newCapacity > 0 && newCapacity < (SHRT_MAX - 1)) {
                    if (realloc(pBD->cb_head, newCapacity)) {
                        pBD->flags |= SET_R_FLAG;
                        pBD->cb_head[pBD->addc_offset] = symbol;
                        pBD->addc_offset++;
                        pBD->capacity = (short)newCapacity;
                        ptr =  realloc(pBD->cb_head, newCapacity);
                        pBD->cb_head = ptr;
                        return pBD;
                    }
                    else {

                        return NULL;
                    }


                }
                else {
                    if (newCapacity > 0 && newCapacity >= (SHRT_MAX - 1)) {
                        newCapacity = SHRT_MAX - 1;
                        if (realloc(pBD->cb_head, newCapacity)) {
                            pBD->flags |= SET_R_FLAG;
                            pBD->cb_head[pBD->addc_offset] = symbol;
                            pBD->addc_offset++;
                            pBD->capacity = (short) newCapacity;
                            ptr = realloc(pBD->cb_head, newCapacity);
                            pBD->cb_head = ptr;
                            return pBD;
                        }
                        else {

                            return NULL;
                        }


                    }
                    else {
                        if (newCapacity <= 0) {
                            return NULL;

                        }



                    }

                }
                break;
            case -1:
                if (pBD->capacity >= SHRT_MAX -1) {

                    return NULL;


                }
                else {
                    availableSpace = SHRT_MAX - 1 - pBD->capacity;
                    newIncrement = (long)(availableSpace * inc_factor/100);
                    newCapacity = (short)(pBD->capacity + newIncrement);
                    if (newCapacity >= SHRT_MAX-1) {
                        newCapacity = SHRT_MAX - 1;

                    }
                    else {

                        if (newCapacity > 0 && newCapacity < SHRT_MAX - 1) {
                            if (realloc(pBD->cb_head, newCapacity)) {
                                pBD->flags |= SET_R_FLAG;
                                pBD->cb_head[pBD->addc_offset] = symbol;
                                pBD->addc_offset++;
                                pBD->capacity = (short)newCapacity;
                                ptr = realloc(pBD->cb_head, newCapacity);
                                pBD->cb_head = ptr;
                                return pBD;
                            }
                            else {

                                return NULL;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }



                break;

            }


        }
}

int b_clear(Buffer* const pBD) {
    pBD->addc_offset = 0;
    pBD->getc_offset = 0;
    pBD->markc_offset = 0;
    pBD->flags = DEFAULT_FLAGS;

    return 1;

}
void b_free(Buffer* const pBD) {

    free(pBD->cb_head);
    free(pBD);


}
short b_capacity(Buffer* const pBD) {
    if (pBD->capacity != 0) {
        return pBD->capacity;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }

}

short b_addcoffset(Buffer* const pBD) {
    if (pBD->addc_offset != 0 ) {
        return pBD->addc_offset;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }

}

short b_markc(pBuffer const pBD, short mark) {
    if (mark<0 || mark > pBD->addc_offset) {

        return -1;
    }
    else {

        pBD->markc_offset = mark;
        return pBD->markc_offset;
    }

}

short b_getcoffset(Buffer* const pBD) {
    if (pBD->getc_offset >=0) {
        return pBD->getc_offset;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }


}
int b_mode(Buffer* const pBD) {

    if (pBD->mode) {
        return pBD->mode;
    }
    else {
        printf("Not found");
    }



}

size_t b_incfactor(Buffer* const pBD) {
    unsigned char inc_factor = pBD->inc_factor;
    size_t inc_factor_value = inc_factor;
    if (pBD->inc_factor) {


        return inc_factor_value;
    }
    else {
        return 0x100;
    }



}

char b_getc(Buffer* const pBD) {
    if (pBD->getc_offset > pBD->addc_offset) {
        return -2;

    }
    else {
        if (pBD->getc_offset == pBD->addc_offset) {
            pBD->flags &= RESET_EOB;
            pBD->flags |= SET_EOB;
            pBD->getc_offset++;
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            pBD->flags &= RESET_EOB;
            pBD->getc_offset++;
            return pBD->cb_head[pBD->getc_offset];


        }

    }



}
int b_print(Buffer* const pBD, char nl) {

    while (b_eob(pBD)==0) {

            printf("%c", b_getc(pBD));



    }
    if (nl != 0) {
        printf("\n");
    }

    return nl;







}



int b_eob(Buffer* const pBD) {
    if ((pBD->flags & CHECK_EOB) > 0) {
        return pBD->flags & CHECK_EOB;


    }
    else {
        if ((pBD->flags & CHECK_EOB) == 0) {

            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }

    }

}


char b_rflag(Buffer* const pBD) {
    if ((pBD->flags & CHECK_R_FLAG) > 0) {
        return pBD->flags & CHECK_R_FLAG ;


    }
    else {
        if ((pBD->flags & CHECK_R_FLAG) == 0) {

            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }

    }

}

int b_isfull(Buffer* const pBD) {
    if (pBD->addc_offset == pBD->capacity) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        if (pBD->addc_offset < pBD->capacity) {
            return 1;

        }
        else {
            return -1;

        }
    }


}


int b_isempty(Buffer* const pBD) {
    if (pBD->addc_offset == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        if (pBD->addc_offset > 0) {
            return 0;

        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

}



char* b_location(Buffer* const pBD, short loc_offset) {
    if ( loc_offset > pBD->addc_offset) {
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        return &pBD->cb_head[loc_offset];

    }




}


int b_load(FILE* const fi, Buffer* const pBD) {
    while (!feof(fi)) {

        char symbol = (char)fgetc(fi);
        if (b_addc(pBD, symbol) != NULL) {



        }
        else {

            ungetc(symbol, fi);
            return LOAD_FAIL;

        }



    }
    return pBD->addc_offset;



}

Buffer* b_compact(Buffer* const pBD, char symbol) {
    short newCapacity = pBD->addc_offset+1;
    char * ptr = (char *)realloc(pBD, newCapacity);
    pBD->cb_head = ptr;
    pBD->capacity = (short)newCapacity;
    pBD->cb_head[pBD->addc_offset] = symbol;
    pBD->addc_offset++;
    pBD->flags &= RESET_R_FLAG;
    pBD->flags |= SET_R_FLAG;

    return pBD;


}

short b_retract(Buffer* const pBD) {
    if (pBD->getc_offset <= 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {

        pBD->getc_offset--;
        return pBD->getc_offset;
    }


}
short b_reset(Buffer* const pBD) {
    if (pBD->getc_offset > pBD->addc_offset || pBD->markc_offset < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        pBD->getc_offset = pBD->markc_offset;
    }

    return pBD->getc_offset;

}

int b_rewind(Buffer* const pBD) {

    pBD->getc_offset = 0;
        pBD->markc_offset = 0;
        return 0;
}
<!-- -->
```

My buffer.h

```
#ifndef BUFFER_H_
#define BUFFER_H_

/*#pragma warning(1:4001) *//*to enforce C89 type comments  - to make //comments an warning */

/*#pragma warning(error:4001)*//* to enforce C89 comments - to make // comments an error */

/* standard header files */
#include <stdio.h>  /* standard input/output */
#include <malloc.h> /* for dynamic memory allocation*/
#include <limits.h> /* implementation-defined data type ranges and limits */

/* constant definitions */
#define RT_FAIL_1 (-1)         /* operation failure return value 1 */
#define RT_FAIL_2 (-2)         /* operation failure return value 2 */
#define LOAD_FAIL (-2)         /* load fail return value */

#define DEFAULT_INIT_CAPACITY 200   /* default initial buffer capacity */
#define DEFAULT_INC_FACTOR 15       /* default increment factor */


/* You should add your own constant definitions here */

/* Add your bit-masks constant definitions here */
#define DEFAULT_FLAGS  0xFFF9 
#define SET_EOB  0x0002 
#define RESET_EOB 0xFFFD
#define CHECK_EOB 0x0002
#define SET_R_FLAG  0x0004
#define RESET_R_FLAG 0xFFFB
#define CHECK_R_FLAG 0x0004
#define DEFAULTZ    0x0000   /* 0000 0000 0000 0000 */


#define SET_LSB     0x0001   /* 0000 0000 0000 0001 */
#define RESET_LSB   0xFFFE   /* 1111 1111 1111 1110 */
#define CHK_LSB     0x0001   /* 0000 0000 0000 0001 */

/* user data type declarations */
typedef struct BufferDescriptor {
    char *cb_head;   /* pointer to the beginning of character array (character buffer) */
    short capacity;    /* current dynamic memory size (in bytes) allocated to character buffer */
    char  inc_factor; /* character array increment factor */
    char  mode;       /* operational mode indicator*/
    unsigned short flags;     /* contains character array reallocation flag and end-of-buffer flag */
    short addc_offset;  /* the offset (in chars) to the add-character location */
    short getc_offset;  /* the offset (in chars) to the get-character location */
    short markc_offset; /* the offset (in chars) to the mark location */
} Buffer, *pBuffer;
/*typedef Buffer *pBuffer;*/

/* function declarations */
/*
Place your function declarations here.
Do not include the function header comments here.
Place them in the buffer.c file
*/
Buffer* b_allocate(short init_capacity, char inc_factor, char o_mode);
pBuffer b_addc(pBuffer const pBD, char symbol);
int b_clear(Buffer* const pBD);
void b_free(Buffer* const pBD);
int b_isfull(Buffer* const pBD);
short b_addcoffset(Buffer* const pBD);
short b_capacity(Buffer* const pBD);
short b_markc(pBuffer const pBD, short mark);
int b_mode(Buffer* const pBD);
size_t b_incfactor(Buffer* const pBD);
int b_load(FILE* const fi, Buffer* const pBD);
int b_isempty(Buffer* const pBD);
char b_getc(Buffer* const pBD);
int b_eob(Buffer* const pBD);
int b_print(Buffer* const pBD, char nl);
Buffer* b_compact(Buffer* const pBD, char symbol);
char b_rflag(Buffer* const pBD);
short b_retract(Buffer* const pBD);
short b_reset(Buffer* const pBD);
short b_getcoffset(Buffer* const pBD);
int b_rewind(Buffer* const pBD);
char* b_location(Buffer* const pBD, short loc_offset);
```

If I try to countinue with debugging, it output : `Unhandled exception at 0x774DFA1D (ntdll.dll) in buffer.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x7751B960).` and `Unhandled exception at 0x7743C5D7 (ntdll.dll) in buffer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00985A7A.`. If I build this and run it in release mode, it cause assertion violation.

Comment: `pBuffer bufferStructure = (pBuffer) calloc(init_capacity, sizeof(Buffer));`. You don't check the return value of `calloc` before derefencing the result. The first time `b_allocate` is called the `init_capacity` value is `0`. Why do you assume `calloc` will return a valid pointer with such a `0` value?

Comment: It seems your code should compile on Linux. You can try our debugging tool by following this [instruction](https://www.cee.studio/segfault.html). Let me know if you run into any problems.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you, I have looked at my function and fixed a lot of program logic problem and the violation has disappeared, somehow.

Comment: the posted code includes a file: `buffer.h`  BUT is missing the contents of that file.  How do you expect us to reproduce the problem and help you debug it when you have not given us all the critical information?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  running it through the compiler results in dozens of error and warning messages.  Please correct the posted code.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: regarding your statement: *I'm trying to write a buffer using C, it was supposed to take in contents from an input file and output it to another text file.*  That is:  char buffer[1024],  two calls to `fopen()` followed by a loop that calls `fread()` followed by fwrite()` and after exiting the loop, two calls to `fclose()`.  So what is all that other code about?

Comment: @user3629249 Sorry, I added the header file now

Comment: Thanks for adding the contents of the header file.  However, if that is ALL the contents of the header file, then it is missing the final statement: `#endif`

Comment: OT: regarding: `if (!b_print(ptr_Buffer,1)) printf("empty buffer\n");`  for ease of readability and understanding: 1)  please follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: `} Buffer, *pBuffer;`  it leads to confusion to hide a pointer in a `typedef`

Comment: regarding: `#include "buffer.h";
#include <string.h>;
#include <stdlib.h>;`  there should NOT be a semicolon `;` after the `#include` statements.  Note: a comment is allowed

Comment: regarding the function: `b_mode()`  This is declared to return a `int` value, but neither the `else` code block, nor the main line of the function returns any value.  This causes the compiler to output: *untitled1.c:565:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]*  Suggest correcting that logic.   Especially since the one call to that function: `printf( "The operational mode of the buffer is:   %d\n", b_mode( ptr_Buffer ) );` is expecting to always get a returned value.  So that function needs to be fixed

Comment: regarding: `Buffer* bufferStructure = calloc(init_capacity, sizeof(Buffer));`  If, as the code later tests for, the value in `init_capacity` is 0, then this call to `calloc()` will (at best) return a NULL pointer.  That will be a problem in the following code, which is expecting the returned value from `calloc()` to point to allocated memory of `sizeof Buffer`.   As with any call to a C library function, need to check for an error.  Suggest this call:  if (init_capacity == 0) 
        {
            init_capacity = DEFAULT_INIT_CAPACITY;` be done before the call to `calloc()`

Comment: regarding: `if( ansi_c )
    {
        err_printf( "Date: %s  Time: %s",__DATE__, __TIME__ );
        err_printf( "ERROR: Compiler is not ANSI C compliant!\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }`  this is not checking for the right thing.  Suggest: `#ifdef ANSI ... #endif`

Comment: There are plenty more problems in the code, but the (above) comments should get you started in the right direction